# Do I have to always call 'init' after 'alloc'?

Tags: objective-c

Do I have to call `init` everytime I call `alloc`? if it is necessary , what should I do in my custom class `init`?

Comment: See about garbage collector in objective-c - that will be explained

Comment: @RagenDazs garbage collector? how is it related? and it is deprecated in favour of ARC

Comment: @BryanChen that's the point, it's fully explained in a lot of books and articles

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. -init has nothing to do with the garbage collector, and searching for info on the garbage collector will not explain it.

Comment: @RagenDazs sorry I did not see your point. are you saying this question so trivial not worth asking? feel free to votedown/flag/close but not saying something misleading. BTW GC is not well explained concept in ObjC because no many people use it.

Comment: Unless you really, really know what you're doing, yes -- you must always do alloc/init as a pair.

Answer (score 2):

Basic answer is yes. The alloc will create the space and the init is what gives it the ability to hold data.

Could optionally use new which is both alloc and init combined.

```
ClassC *c = [ClassC new];
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite sure why `new` is so rarely used.

Comment: I'd guess that is because automatic reference counting was introduced later. [class new] doesn't give an option of calling retain or autorelease. That is not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about classes derived from NSObject, first question is already answered by [tateyaku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3381598/tateyaku). Yes, you need to call `init` method to allow for super classes proper initialisation.

Second one: You do not need to implement your class init method unless you need to initialise your class members.

If you do then:

```
-(id)init
{
    if ((self=[super init]))  // call super init function
    {
        _your_data = ...; // initialise an ivar
    }

    return self; // successful init returns a non null pointer otherwise return is 0
}
```

You may define an init method with a different signature, e.g.

```
-(id)initWithLabel:(NSString*)label {...}
```

Comment: I thins this code Xcode paste in each custom class. So, not necessary to show it to topic starter one more time.

Comment: I've never had Xcode paste this in.  But then I never use their templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `init` after `alloc`:

```
NSString *str = [NSString alloc];
// some code
str = [str init];
```

in some cases you should not use `init` at all.

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSManagedContext *context = ... 
[NSManagedContext save:&err]; //manager context will init err by yourself.
```

what should you do in your custom class:

You should call `[super methodName];` in each overrided (not custom) method. `init` is not exception.

Comment: Your example of not calling init is confusing at least. If you do not create an object you don't need to call init obviously, do you think?